# Access VBA keypress

Tags: ms-access, vba

When my cursor is over my textbox and I press than on the button "+" My value of that textbox has to go up by 1

So what I tried is using MouseMove but the problem is here that I can't use the function KeyAscii that I have in the function OnkeyPress

```
If KeyAscii = vbKeyL Then
    Stock.Value = Stock.Value + 1
End If
```

If you have any idea, your free to post!
thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Right Answer was:
Put Key preview on Yes in the form, Textbox enabled: False

And than in the keyDown event:

```
Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyAdd

             Stock.Value = Stock.Value + 1
    End Select
```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for this.  I had tried all kinds of things with the `Form_keypress` event, trying to enable a function call when the user pushes the `escape` key, but it would never work if any control had first received focus. But with `key preview` enabled, it works all the time now.  Wonderful!  You should mark your question solved.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
if KeyAscii = vbKeyAdd Then // vb KeyAdd is the key code constant for the '+' key
     Stock.Value = Stock.Value + 1
End If
```

try declaring it like this

```
Dim key as KeyAscii
```

then change you code like this

```
Dim key as KeyAscii
if key = vbKeyAdd Then // vb KeyAdd is the key code constant for the '+' key
         Stock.Value = Stock.Value + 1
    End If
```

And here is a list of all the vba key codes

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

hope this helps

Comment: Thnx for the KeyAdd but my big problem is still that "KeyAscii" doesnt exist in the OnMouseMove function, only in the OnKeyPress it exists

Comment: I tried it but when I try to compile it gives me an error because it can't find the key [link](http://prntscr.com/1ay74x)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the **MouseMove** event of the textbox and the **KeyPress** event.

Using the **MouseMove** event, you can know when your mouse is above your textbox. If it is, set a global variable to True, and when it leaves (when it hits the border of your textbox) set it to False.

Then on the form **KeyPress** event, check if your global variable is true, and if so, then check the KeyAscii value.